# How to disable specific hours in specific dates in jquery datetimepicker (xdan)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using [jQuery DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker). I want to disable some specific hours in some specific dates. For example, I want to disable `09:00AM` on `29/03/2022` and `10:00AM` on `30/03/2022`.

I already found this code, but it doesn't work. The inline calendar is running correctly.

```js
var specificDates = ['29/03/2022', '30/03/2022'];
var hoursToTakeAway = [
  [09, 10],
  [10]
];

onGenerate: function(ct, $i) {
  var ind = specificDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'));
  $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').show();
  if (ind !== -1) {
    $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').each(function(index) {
      if (hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: if u add go for $(this).addClass('xdsoft_disabled'); instead of $(this).hide() ?
Or better go for $(this).addClass('hidden')?

Comment: Thanx for help, I just tested and it didn't work. I can still choose the hours.

Comment: You should try also with https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#runtime_options and iterate each time for try to disable it

Comment: Thanx for the tips, but i don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Ok i have some news : i just modified this line : `var ind = specificDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'));` to : `var ind = specificDates.indexOf(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));` Now its disable 9 and 10 on ALL DAYS

Comment: It's working ! :D Thanx for your help @Weber , `$(this).addClass('xdsoft_disabled');` was helpfull.

Comment: Please don't post the solution inside the question instead create an answer

Comment: Ok no problem, thanx for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL CODE IS WORKING : ( i'm using momentjs to use moment function on ct)

```
onGenerate: function(ct,$i) {
    var ind = specificDates.indexOf(moment(ct).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').show();

    if(ind !== -1) {
        $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').each(function(index){
            if(hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1) {
                $(this).addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
            }
        });
    }
}
```